# C++ - Why is this implementation of fibonacci memoization using map so slow?

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am trying to implement a fibonacci function in c++ using memoization. My implementation works but is extremely slow. **Why is my implementation so slow?** I've seen a similar implementations in javascript using an object for memoization and they were blazing fast. **Is it because I used the map data structure?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

unsigned int fib(unsigned short n, std::map<unsigned short, unsigned int> memo = {});

int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " " << fib(i) << std::endl;
    }
};

unsigned int fib(unsigned short n, std::map<unsigned short, unsigned int> memo)
{
    if (memo.find(n) != memo.end())
    {
        return memo.find(n)->second;
    }
    if (n <= 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    memo.insert(
        std::pair<unsigned short, unsigned int>(
            n, fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo)));

    return memo.find(n)->second;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between passing parameters by reference and by value? Are you aware that passing parameters by value requires duplicating the entire parameter. How long do you think it takes to make a duplicate copy of your map? And because of the manner of the recursion call, absolutely nothing useful actually gets memoized?

Comment: Note also since the map is _not_ passed by reference, the memoization never happens at all and so this algorithm has roughly factorial time complexity.  Using recursion to calculate this series is so pointless, it's upsetting that it seems to be used as an example for learning memoization.  There are way better algorithms that have a practical application.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik paddy Thank you so much for your replies. I've just started coding in C++ so I had no idea that was happening. I really appreciate your help

Comment: From a usability perspective, rather than require the caller to allocate and pass `memo`, I'd recommend you make a simple class that contains this structure as a private member.  Then, create a `get(unsigned short)` member function that retrieves/computes the value.  This way, any memory associated with the memoization is automatically cleaned up when the caller no longer needs the "fibonacci" object.  As an extension, that method could be made `const` and the memo structure `mutable`. Consider `std::unordered_map` for better performance.  Or, actually, `std::vector` would be the ideal choice.

Comment: @HaziqMuhammad -- *I had no idea that was happening* -- C++ is a value-based language.  That means that when you do this `a = b;` or `func(Object a);  ... Object b: func(b);` actual copies are made, and not references passed or assigned.  I'm assuming you have only used reference-based languages in the past.  This is a major difference between JavaScript or Python and C++.  Thus you must be careful when you assign, pass, or return values in C++.

Comment: @paddy Would I be able to relate keys and values using a vector?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?  The nature of your memoization for the fibonacci sequence is that your keys are sequential values.  So they could just be indices into a `vector` or `deque`

Comment: @paddy How would I extend that to memoization problems like this one where a multivariable function is being memoized: [Rectangular Grid Walk](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rectangular-grid-walk-no-restriction)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
, std::map<unsigned short, unsigned int> memo)
```

that is a copy of a map.

You are copying your memoization map every call, then forgetting anything you added to it.

```
unsigned int fib(unsigned short n, std::map<unsigned short, unsigned int>* memo = nullptr);

unsigned int fib(unsigned short n, std::map<unsigned short, unsigned int>* pmemo)
{
  std::map<unsigned short, unsigned int> local;
  auto& memo = pmemo?*pmemo:local;
```

then pass `&memo` to the recursive call of `fib`.

This uses up a touch of extra stack space on each recursive call, but only worth worrying about if you are doing 100,000+ calls.

```
unsigned int fib(unsigned short n)
{
  std::map<unsigned short, unsigned int> memo = {
    {0u,0u},
    {1u,1u},
    {2u,1u},
  };
  std::vector<unsigned short> todo = {n};
  while (!todo.empty()) {
    // solved?
    if (memo.find(todo.back()) != memo.end())
    {
      todo.pop_back();
      continue;
    }

    unsigned short a = todo.back()-1;
    unsigned short b = todo.back()-2;
    auto ita = memo.find(a);
    auto itb = memo.find(b);

    // solved?
    if (ita != memo.end() && itb !=  memo.end())
    {
       memo.insert( {todo.back(), ita->second+itb->second} );
       todo.pop_back();
       continue;
    }
    todo.push_back(a);
    todo.push_back(b); // could skip this actually
  }
  return memo.find(n)->second;
}
```

this is an example of manually maintaining the "call stack" of things todo instead of using recursive calls.